Approximating a regular pentagon with lattice points in the plane
Inspired by this question it is asked here:
Can a regular pentagon be closely approximated by placing the vertices on lattice points $(m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ in the plane?
By "closely approximated" is meant: the vertices of a true regular pentagon are all on or arbitrarily close to the chosen lattice points for some pentagon, analogously to the trianglar case in the referenced question.
We would expect that as with the triangular case, a larger polygon would be needed to satisfy a closer tolerance. The problem is made more difficult by having to approximate multiple irrational length ratios simultaneously in the pentagonal case.

This is too long for a commentbor to post neatly into the body of the question. Here I propose one method with numerical evidence that this will give arbitrarily close approximations of the regular vertices with lattice points given a sufficiently large pentagon; thereby the question is answered affirmatively.
We begin by idenyifying five points with real coordinates that are vertices of an exact regular pentagon:
$A=(0,0)$
$B=(2q,0)$
$C=((\phi+1)q,\sqrt{\phi^2+1}q)$
$D=(q,\phi\sqrt{\phi^2+1}q)$
$E=((-\phi+1)q,\sqrt{\phi^2+1}q)$
where $\phi$ is the golden ratio $(1+\sqrt5)/2$ and $q$ is an integer scaling factor. By construction $A$ and $B$ are exact lattice points. The other vertices will be approximated by the nearest lattice points and will be labeled $C',D',E'$.
With any sufficiently large value of $q$ we can approach the shape of the regular pentagon with any precision, but matching the lattice points with the regular-pentagon vertices to arbitrary precision requires more selectivity. With an equilateral triangle we use continued fractions to identify favorble scaling factors. It turns out that a more subtle approach based on continued fractions works for the regular pentagon.
We select the coefficient in the $y$ coordinate of $D$ ($\phi\sqrt{\phi^2+1}$) for this analysis. This parameter satisfies the irreducible quartic equation $x^4-10x^2+5=0$ and so would give an irregular, nonperiodic contulinued fraction if expanded with integer coefficients. However, if we allow the inclusion of $\phi$ in the coefficients the following is realized:
$\phi\sqrt{\phi^2+1}=[\phi^2,\overline{2,2\phi^2}].$
Not only is this periodic, it has alternating coefficients of $2\phi^2\approx5.236$, and so we might expect truncations after an even number $2k$ of coefficients to give good approximations with relatively small denominators. To get these denominators into integer form we will subsequently have to approximate $\phi$. The natural approach is to use a ratio of Fibonacci numbers; numerical investigations suggest that
$\phi\approx F_{4k+2}/F_{4k+1}$
works well and will be used here. Here $F_j$ is the $j$-th entry in the Fibonacci sequence $1,1,2,3,5,8,...$.
Let us explore what happens with $k=2$ as an example. We have
$\phi\sqrt{\phi^2+1}\approx[\phi^2,2,2\phi^2,2]=(32\phi+25)/(8\phi+12)$.
where after simplifying the continued fraction we plug in $\phi^2=\phi+1$ to remove powers of $\phi$ higher than the first. To seven significant digits this fraction is $3.077945$ versus $\phi\sqrt{\phi^2+1}=3.077684$. We now put in $\phi\approx F_{10}/F_9=55/34$. Multiplying numerator and denominator by $F_9=34$ to simplify the resulting complex fraction then yields
$\phi\sqrt{\phi^2+1}\approx\dfrac{(32×55)+(25×34)}{(8×55)+(12×34)}=2610/848$
$(3.077830\text{ vs }3.077684)$
We do not reduce this fraction to lower terms than those obtained by using $F_9$ as the multiplier above, because we have to allow for the other vertices to have odd coordinates (or generally coordinates not divisible by any nonunit factor of $F_{4k+1}$). We will find this to be the case indeed at $C'$ and $E'$.
We then choose the denominator in this approximation, $848$, as our $q$ value and plug into the regular pentagon vertices as given above. Rounding $C,D,E$ to the nearest lattice points then gives
$A=(0,0)
$B=(1696,0)$
$C'=(2220,1613); C\approx(2220.0928,1612.991)$
$D'=(848,2610); D\approx(848,2609.8756)$
$E'=(-524,1613); E\approx(-523.9172,1612.991)$
The maximum distance from any lattice point approximant to the actual regular-pentagon vertex occurs at $D,D'$ and to five decimal places this is $0.12436$.
This seems not all that good, but the real objectivebis to identify a sequence of ever-closer approximations by this method. Calculating the approximants filor $k=1,2,3,4$ gives the following results for the lattice point aporoximants and the maximil distance that occurs between $D$ and $D'$:
$k=1: A=(0,0)(\text{ all} k); B=(20,0); C'=(26,19); D'=(10,31); E'=(-6,19); d(D,D')\approx\color{blue}{0.22316}$
$k=2: B=(1696,0); C'=(2220,1613); D'=(848,2610); E'=(-524,1613); d(D,D')\approx\color{blue}{0.12436}$
$k=3: B=(144044,0); C'=(188556,136994); D'=(72022,221661); E'=(-44512,136994); d(D,D')\approx\color{blue}{0.07629}$
$k=3l4: B=(12233968,0); C'=(16014472,11635195); D'=(6116984,18826141); E'=(-3780504,11635195); d(D,D')\approx\color{blue}{0.04604}$
The maximal distances appear to decrease roughly in a geometrical progression, and this trend may be expected to continue as the approximation errors in $\phi\sqrt{\phi^2+1}$ and $\phi$ are also decreasing roughly in geometric progression.
Thereby a sequence of lattice-point pentagins with vertices approaching zero distance from a regular pentagon vertices is deemed to exist.
